# Real time chat using kafka

Tags: design-patterns, apache-kafka, chat

I am building a chat service that supports one to one and group chat.
Users connect to a LoadBalancer which assigns them to one of the running server app.

```
user1                     Server1     
user2  -> LoadBalancer -> Server2  => Kafka Message Bus
user3                     Server3
```

Suppose user1 connects to Server1 and user3 connects to Server3.
When user1 sends a message to user3, Server1 will publish that message to kafka on a topic **chat.message**. The message envelope contains the recipient info (recipient=user3).
When Server3 gets the message, it only parses the envelope, checks the recipient, says I have that user connected so I will process it (Server2 does the same thing but drops the message as User3 is not connected to it).

This desgin works good so far.
However, if I have a million Servers, all but one will process the message and rest will drop it. Seems a bit wasteful (although each Service only parses the envelop and not the entire message). Is there a better way to split my topic such that the message is only sent to a subset of the servers and not all of them. I could have topics like **chat.message.server1,2,3**. However, that sounds too granular.

**I realize I can handle this via grpc or rest such that Server1 will directly send the message to Server3. However, I don't want to go that route of hard coupling.

Comment: No, you cannot target specific Kafka brokers... But can you describe if/how you are using consumer groups here? If you want to only consume a subset of data, then you must deploy apps that subscribe to those topics on those servers.

Answer (score 0):

As `only sent to a subset of the servers`, I understand you mean the service that you have called `Server` and not the Kafka servers.

In that case, you could leverage the fact that topics are divided in partitions and that consumers of the same consumer group are assigned a subset of these partitions.

A couple of options:

1. Stateful. You use some kind of distributed database to register to which `Server` is each user assigned and what partitions are each `Server` consuming from. When you want to send a message to a user, you query the database to know in which `Server` it is registered, get the partitions that the `Server` is consuming from, and send it to one of these partitions (and then you cache it locally to not have to query the database continuously). When there is a rebalance (change in the number of `Servers`), you implement a custom hook that updates these mappings in the database before continuing processing messages and each `Server` clean its local caches.
2. Stateless. Your load balancer and the Kafka partition assignment strategy assign clients and partitions to `Servers` in a deterministic way. So a `Server` having to send a message to a client knows to which partition it has to send the message based on a unique id of the client without having to query any external system.

   - You are going to need a deterministic mapping between users and `Servers` and partitions and `Servers`: The load balancer will need to know what `Server` is a particular user assigned to, and when sending a message, the server will need to know 1) in which `Server` is this user and 2) what partitions have this `Server` assigned.
   - This can be fairly complex to get right and may require you to use a hashing technique like [`consistent hashing`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing) to avoid reconnecting all clients to different `Servers` when there is a change in the number of `Servers`.